# How does MPPT algorithm and 2-stage battery charging go together?

Tags: battery-charging, switching-regulator, mppt

I understand that for finding the MPP of a solar panel, the PWM of a switching converter needs to be regulated based on an algorithm. And that if a battery is connected to the converter the output voltage will be constant (that of the battery).
How is a battery supposed to be charged in CC and CV mode if I can only change the current.

Comment: CC is used until the CV level is reached then current declines until cutoff threshold

Comment: CC means "as much current as you can get up to the recommended (CC) figure", so use MPPT here as long as you're within the battery's charging current rating. CV means "enough current to reach this voltage", so turn MPPT off and don't exceed that voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a battery is below its final charging voltage, you charge it in constant current mode (CC) mode. The maximum current you should give it will be given on the data sheet. If it doesn't say, then C/10 should be fairly safe for any battery. Some batteries can be charged much faster. This limits the maximum power a battery can accept in this mode.

When the battery has reached its final charging voltage, you charge it in constant voltage (CV) mode. There are two ways to do this. The first is to switch to a voltage regulator. The second is to keep supplying a controlled current, but reduce that current so the voltage does not exceed the final charge voltage. As the current falls, the battery will be accepting much less charge power than in CC mode.

If the battery can accept more charge power than your panel can generate, then you can use the standard MPPT algorithm. Adjust the PWM until the current sent to the battery is maximised.

If the battery cannot accept all the power the panel generates, then you must use something other than MPPT. Adjust the PWM to get a current limited by the max CC charge rate, or the CV mode final charge voltage.